# Python Pandas: Changing a Column Heading - Getting "Key Error"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to turn the following dataframe (DataFrame A) that has dates in a messy format into a dataframe that just has two columns: Month and Hours Recorded (DataFrame B).

I am running into the following problem: 
I can't seem to isolate the column headings so that I can use .rename to change them into something more legible. Each time I try to isolate it by using 
df['2018-01-01 00:00:00'] for example, it gives me "KeyError: '2018-01-01 00:00:00"

I'm aware of pd.melt but I can't even get my dataframe to that point because I can't change the column headings.

**DataFrame A**
[image]

*emphasized text*

**DataFrame B**

[image]

Comment: So that we can re-create your issue, can you add the output of `df.iloc[0:5,0:5].to_dict()` to your question.

Comment: @ALollz thanks for the reply. Here is the output of that code:
{datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0): {0: 18.5,
  1: nan,
  2: 5.5,
  3: nan,
  4: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 0, 0): {0: 11.0,
  1: nan,
  2: 6.5,
  3: 2.0,
  4: 2.0},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have to do with the fact that the column header is a timestamp object (as opposed to a string e.g.).  What worked for me when I tried to replicate your issue was adding an extra set of parentheses within your brackets.  So instead of:

```
df['2018-01-01 00:00:00']
```

use:

```
df[('2018-01-01 00:00:00')]
```